# Increasing the size of images displayed in Pytorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I want to display few images and their respective labels using Pytorch dataloader.

However the image displayed is very tiny grid.

How do I increase the width of each image so it's bigger.

Here's the code I used:

```
mean_nums = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
std_nums = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]

def imshow(inp, title=None):
    """Imshow for Tensor."""
    inp = inp.numpy().transpose((1, 2, 0))
    mean = np.array(mean_nums)
    std = np.array(std_nums)
    inp = std * inp + mean
    inp = np.clip(inp, 0, 1)
    plt.imshow(inp)
    if title is not None:
        plt.title(title)
    plt.pause(0.001)  # pause a bit so that plots are updated


# Get a batch of training data
inputs, classes = next(iter(dataloaders['trainLoader']))

# Make a grid from batch
out = torchvision.utils.make_grid(inputs,nrow=2)

imshow(out, title=[image_datasets['train'].classes[x] for x in classes])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert `plt.figure(figsize=[width, height])` before `plt.imshow` And choose the `width, height`  that will satisfy you.

So, for example, the `imshow` function may be:

```
def imshow(inp, title=None):
    """Imshow for Tensor."""
    inp = inp.numpy().transpose((1, 2, 0))
    mean = np.array(mean_nums)
    std = np.array(std_nums)
    inp = std * inp + mean
    inp = np.clip(inp, 0, 1)
    plt.figure(figsize=[20, 20])
    plt.imshow(inp)
    if title is not None:
        plt.title(title)
    plt.pause(0.001)  # pause a bit so that plots are updated
```

Comment: its not expanding the image sizes. Image sizes is still small. Attached pic

Answer (score 0):

This is not about inserting `plt.figure(figsize=[20, 20])` , but about inserting it **before calling** `makegrid`.

```
plt.figure(figsize=[20, 20])
out = torchvision.utils.make_grid(inputs,nrow=2)
# ... do whatever you want after ...
plt.imshow(out)
```